# Trying to find a mean within a column that contains np.nan. Having trouble only getting the float values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

testcolumn is filled with strings of numbers and np.nan values.
I am trying to find the mean of the numerical values only. 
The code does not filter out the np.nan values so I don't get the correct values.

```
columnCount = 0
columnMean = 0.0


for x in testcolumn:
    if x != np.nan:
        print(x)
        columnMean = float(x) + columnMean
        columnCount = columnCount + 1

columnMean = columnMean/columnCount
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `numpy.nanmean` with `astype(float)`:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array(['1','2',np.nan])
np.nanmean(arr.astype(float))
```

Output:

```
1.5
```

Comment: I love you i wanna give you a hug

Comment: @TonyHuang Lol. Glad to help :)